# Differential Equations - Correct use and placement of constants c1, c2 etc

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am having difficulty trying to discern how to use constants appropriately.

For a homework problem $xy^2\frac{dy}{dx}=y^3-x^3$ where $y(1)=2$, I make it all the way (using substitution) to $\frac{u^3}{3}+\ln|x|+C$.

Here's where I begin having trouble.  Which side of the problem do I place the $C_1$ on?  My instinct is to place it on the same side as the rest of the equation, but the solution steps have it placed on the other side of the equal sign.

Then, the steps continue by substituting back in $y/x = u$ and then multiplying by $3$ to remove the denominator in the first term.  This is also applied to the $C_1$ constant.

But then, when working towards the solution using the initial condition, the solution author merely says that $C_2=3C_1$ and replaces the $C_1$ with $C_2$, for a final answer of $y^3+3x^3\ln|x|=8x^3$.  The book answer corroborates this.

What?  What happened to the $3C_1$?  Shouldn't this answer be $24x^3$?  Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter "which side", since the two are equivalent.
If you substituted $u = y/x$, you got something equivalent to.
$$ u^2 u' + 1/x = 0$$
and integrating this, you can write the result as either
$$ \dfrac{u^3}{3} + \ln |x| + C_1 = 0$$
or 
$$ \dfrac{u^3}{3} + \ln |x| = C_2 $$
The two are equivalent: $C_1 = -C_2$.
If you do it the first way, substituting back gives you
$$ \dfrac{y^3}{3 x^3} + \ln |x| + C_1 = 0$$
and using the initial condition $x=1,y=2$ in this equation you have $8/3 + 0 + C_1 = 0$, so $C_1 = -8/3$
and then (multiplying everything by $3 x^3$)
$$ y^3 + 3 x^3 \ln |x| - 8 x^3 = 0$$
If you do it the other way, you'll get $C_2 = +8/3$ and then
$$ y^3 + 3 x^3 \ln |x| = 8 x^3 $$

Comment: Thanks Robert.  So which method makes the most sense in this instance?  And is there a hard and fast set of rules when using constants?  I'm just trying to understand the conventions and most common use cases.

Comment: As I said, which side you put it on does not matter at all.  Just choose one and stick with it.  Make sure the form you use when plugging in the initial conditions is the same as the form you put the resulting constant back into.

Comment: Thanks again.  So if I modify the C1 constant, do I need to then assign that result to the C2 constant, and so on and so forth?

Comment: You don't need more than one constant here.  But if for some reason you define a second constant as a function of the first, then if you get a value for the first constant it should determine the value of the other constant according to that function.